# SQL store procedure executes in SQL but not in code

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I need your help. I have a store procedure that executes perfectly in SQL but when I call her from an IActionResult from a .net controller with FromSqlRaw(), returns the following error :

**System.InvalidOperationException: 'The required column 'SeasonGroupClientCode' was not present in the results of a 'FromSql' operation.'**

**in Action:**

```
var sql = "EXECUTE sp_seasonDataGroupedHorizonatlallyByCompany";
                
var list = _context.SeasonGroupedByCompanies.FromSqlRaw(sql).AsNoTracking().ToList();
```

**Store Procedure:**

```
select * from
    (SELECT [SeasonGroupSeasonDescription] AS FirstSeason,[SeasonGroupClientCode] AS 
    FirstSeasonClientCode,[SeasonGroupClientName] AS 
    FistSeasonClientName,SeasonGroupCompanyId],
    SUM([SeasonGroupStartValue]) AS FiSTotalStartValue ,
    SUM([SeasonGroupFinalValue]) AS FiSTotalFinalValue
    FROM [dbo].[SeasonGroupedByCompanies] 
    WHERE [SeasonGroupSeasonDescription]='SS21' 
    GROUP BY [SeasonGroupClientCode],[SeasonGroupClientName],
    [SeasonGroupSeasonDescription],[SeasonGroupCompanyId]) as td
    full join
    (SELECT [SeasonGroupSeasonDescription] AS SecondSeason,[SeasonGroupClientCode] AS 
    SecondSeasonClientCode,[SeasonGroupClientName] AS SecondSeasonClientName, 
    [SeasonGroupCompanyId] AS SecondId,
    SUM([SeasonGroupStartValue]) AS SeSTotalStartValue ,
    SUM([SeasonGroupFinalValue]) AS SeSTotalFinalValue 
    FROM [dbo].[SeasonGroupedByCompanies] 
    WHERE [SeasonGroupSeasonDescription]='FW21' 
    GROUP BY [SeasonGroupClientCode],[SeasonGroupClientName],[SeasonGroupSeasonDescription], 
    [SeasonGroupCompanyId]) as tf 
    on td.FistSeasonClientName = tf.SecondSeasonClientName
     full join
    (SELECT [SeasonGroupSeasonDescription] AS ThirdSeason,[SeasonGroupClientCode] AS 
    ThirdSeasonClientCode,[SeasonGroupClientName] AS ThirdSeasonClientName, 
    [SeasonGroupCompanyId] AS ThirdId,
    SUM([SeasonGroupStartValue]) AS ThSTotalStartValue ,
    SUM([SeasonGroupFinalValue]) AS ThSTotalFinalValue 
    FROM [dbo].[SeasonGroupedByCompanies] 
    WHERE [SeasonGroupSeasonDescription]='SS22' 
    GROUP BY [SeasonGroupClientCode],[SeasonGroupClientName],[SeasonGroupSeasonDescription], 
    [SeasonGroupCompanyId]) as ts 
    on td.FistSeasonClientName = ts.ThirdSeasonClientName 
     full join
    (SELECT [SeasonGroupSeasonDescription] AS FourthSeason,[SeasonGroupClientCode]AS 
    FourthSeasonClientCode,[SeasonGroupClientName] AS FourthSeasonClientName, 
    [SeasonGroupCompanyId] AS FourthId,
    SUM([SeasonGroupStartValue]) AS FoSTotalStartValue ,
    SUM([SeasonGroupFinalValue]) AS FoSTtotalFinalValue 
    FROM [dbo].[SeasonGroupedByCompanies] 
    WHERE [SeasonGroupSeasonDescription]='FW22' 
    GROUP BY [SeasonGroupClientCode],[SeasonGroupClientName],[SeasonGroupSeasonDescription], 
    [SeasonGroupCompanyId]) as tx 
    on td.FistSeasonClientName = tx.FourthSeasonClientName
```

```
Entity

public class SeasonGroupByCompany
    {
        [Key]
        public int SeasonGroupCompanyId { get; set; }
        public string? SeasonGroupSeasonDescription { get; set; }
        public string? SeasonGroupSalesman { get; set; }
        public int SeasonGroupClientCode { get; set; }
        public string? SeasonGroupClientName { get; set; }
        public int SeasonGroupQuantity { get; set; }
        public int SeasonGroupDiscount { get; set; }

      
        public double SeasonGroupStartValue { get; set; }

       
        public double SeasonGroupFinalValue { get; set; }
```

The same error comes up, even if I run the query directly from FromRawSql().
Thanks in advance, any help will be appreciated

Comment: i'm assuming the proc you are calling needs the param `SeasonGroupClientCode` passed into it. Would be able to make a proper assumption if you showed the entire sql proc tho

Comment: There is no parameter

Answer (score 0):

It looks like in the `SeasonGroupedByCompany` entity you have a field named `SeasonGroupClientCode`, but in the SQL query you have renamed it into `FirstSeasonClientCode`:

```
...[SeasonGroupClientCode] AS FirstSeasonClientCode...
```

Either rename the field in the entity, or don't rename the column in SQL, because originally the naming looks to be consistent.

Comment: Don't rename only the first occurence of SeasonGroupClientCode. The other three occurences which you join SHOULD be renamed, because it would result with duplicated column names.

Comment: If I don't rename, the error is: The specific column already exists .I want to achieve a full join  result into one table , which in SMSS works perfectly

Comment: OK, lets see it the other way. Please show the SeasonGroupedByCompany class so we can see how query result matches the entity structure.

Comment: I've add entity